# Typescript - Return object with same keys as argument object

Tags: typescript

The return object needs to have only the keys that the argument object has and the keys have to be strings.

This is what I have so far:

```js
type ArgumentObject<Key extends string> = Record<Key, string>;

type ResultObject<Key extends string> = Record<Key, boolean>;

function someFunction<Key extends string>(arg: ArgumentObject<Key>) {

  const result: ResultObject<keyof typeof arg> = {} as ResultObject<Key>;

  for (const k in Object.keys(arg)) {
    result[k as Key] = true;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Typescript correctly infers the shape of the result object only if the keys of the argument object are strings. But you can also put `number` and `symbol` as keys in the argument object.

```js
const result = someFunction({
  a: "abc",
  b: "def",
  1: "number allowed as key",
  [Symbol("a")]: "symbol also"
})

result.a // intellisense doesn't work

/////////////////////////////////////

const result = someFunction({
  a: "abc",
  b: "def"
})

result.a // intellisense works
```

Also, it would be great to not have to do all the type casting with `as`.

Answer (score 1):

First, there might be a misconception: when you provide a numeric index as a property when defining an object literal, it is coerced to a `string`. So in your example, `1` is a string, not a number:

```js
{
  a: "abc",
  b: "def",
  1: "number allowed as key",
  [Symbol("a")]: "symbol also"
}
```

TypeScript is [structurally-typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html), so as long as a type can `extend` (be a subtype of) a required type, the compiler will allow it. In your case, the object passes the requirement of having string keys with string values (it also happens to have a symbol key).

One way to handle this is to use a [conditional return type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), where in the valid branch, it is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html). So, while you can still pass in objects that have undesirable properties, you won't be able to use the return value if you do.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgWwKYDFzXkgHgBVEMAPKDMAE2UQCUMI4AnaggBRbgAcMWoATwDSGQQBoUUFjDABzAHwKAFAEMWcgFyIiASm3JBaAEZwANqQpVaiANZi4wHYgD8iMBgBu-RNrAgTH3JKGjp7QUdnNw9vFl9EAG8AKEREAG1hRFk7ByciAF1tU3MMVTAAbiSAX0SUxGYwZChEFgxkEDNmgF5EmtU6MsFK1OBWRGUGprsspAB5YwArJigAOnDkNQ1dXRa2jqg020R+nIi8-MQe6RAMYd2oEBYkVvbOyqqkpMnml-2ARkuKHQ2FwsAQymSqVU2gARKpjBAYeI6sZYdQMMAkXU-rD-IE4qozGY4AB3DDUY5hMRY1JpADKRlMZmUcJhukKiBhhhM5mOZlQWKqukqSV+nT+5UQAHope4vPxRXtxStVJKpQAqOqpbWIAB6SS4vH4QkQAHJVKbENQ4G13HBmuQYFMEIghHwzTF+KaVsoAEwAZn9AE4duqpZ9vrtXlBfYDUJgcJAwWAIXVoYgACy+yQaur6oiCd2mvHGL1ZOhge2U5AwORgeFmDCuuCuwtN01NGTyb1+-2+32h8OpVGc9GY6rCz5imNq2WeliK6O+lVqzU6nX6w18ASCM0Wq02itVx3OpBu9vznsB4ODiMIKbT-1x4GJvDgyHHWHwxHI4dojEwhOIqPrOiSfogxSNmUkojpBpQVIgHyPiu0qynBZRAA)

```ts
function someFunction <T extends Record<PropertyKey, string>>(arg: T): symbol extends keyof T ? never : number extends keyof T ? never : {
  [K in keyof T]: boolean;
} {
  const result = {} as any;
  for (const k in Object.keys(arg)) result[k as keyof T] = true;
  return result;
}

const result1 = someFunction({
  a: "abc",
  b: "def",
  1: "number allowed as key",
  [Symbol("a")]: "symbol also",
});

result1; // never
result1.a; /*
        ^
Property 'a' does not exist on type 'never'.(2339) */

const result2 = someFunction({
  a: 42, /*
  ^
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322) */
  b: "def"
});

result2; // never
result2.a; /*
        ^
Property 'a' does not exist on type 'never'.(2339) */

const result3 = someFunction({
  a: "abc",
  b: "def"
});

result3; // { a: boolean; b: boolean; }
result3.a; // boolean
```